# Kotlin Map.get throws NoSuchElementException when wrapped with Jetpack Compose 'by mutableStateMapOf' (SnapshotStateMap)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Element accessors on a map should return `null` on non-existing keys, but instead

`myMapOfThings["item3"]` throws `java.util.NoSuchElementException: Key item3 is missing in the map.`

When a Map is initialized (via SnapshotStateMap) in ViewModel with

```
var myMapOfThings: MutableMap<String, MyType> by mutableStateMapOf(
    "item1" to MyType(),
    "item2" to MyType()
)
```

All documentation seems to indicate it should behave as a true map

```
* Create a instance of [MutableMap]<K, V> that is observable and can be snapshot.
* @see mutableMapOf
```

and as declared for Map in `package kotlin.collections`

```
/**
* Returns the value corresponding to the given [key], or `null` if such a key is not present in the map.
*/
public operator fun get(key: K): V?
```

**Is this a bug or am I missing something?**

(Build Info for Reference)

```
kotlin_version = '1.8.0'
kotlin_plugin_version = '1.7.0'
compose_version = '1.2.0'
coroutines_version = '1.6.1'

compileSdk 32
buildToolsVersion = "30.0.3"
minSdk 28
targetSdk 32

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are initializing using delegated property. When you click on by it will be pointing to `MapAccesors.kt` . Delegated map implementation is a wrapper(overridden) of original map interface. When you use `by` Delegate property to initialize values it will be pointing to overriden funtion. Here you can see it throws `NoSuchElementException` if not present.

```
@kotlin.jvm.JvmName("getOrImplicitDefaultNullable")
@PublishedApi
internal fun <K, V> Map<K, V>.getOrImplicitDefault(key: K): V {
    if (this is MapWithDefault)
        return this.getOrImplicitDefault(key)

    return getOrElseNullable(key, { throw NoSuchElementException("Key $key is missing in the map.") })
}


@kotlin.jvm.JvmName("getVar")
@kotlin.internal.InlineOnly
public inline operator fun <V, V1 : V> MutableMap<in String, out @Exact V>.getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): V1 =
    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST") (getOrImplicitDefault(property.name) as V1)
```

One way to fix is to initialize with `=` instead of using `by`.

```
var myMapOfThings: MutableMap<String, MyType> = mutableStateMapOf(
    "item1" to MyType(),
    "item2" to MyType()
)
```